# Not able to download jQuery 1.9.1

Tags: jquery

I need to download jQuery 1.9.1.js. Everywhere I could find CDN link like

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.js"></script>
```

and NuGet installation like this

```
PM> Install-Package jQuery -Version 1.9.1
```

I need the physical js file of this version specifically. I have tried to search and I have found one URL

```
http://www.oldapps.com/
```

But this is giving the js upto 1.7, not above that. All i can find is only cdn links.

Where can I download this?

Comment: Download it from the CDN link yourself? http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: you finding it on dead link use @RoryMcCrossan given link.

Answer (score 7):

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js

or

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js (for the minified version)

then do "file->save as" or CTRL+S in your browser

Answer (score 1):

**Use this reference to get the 1.9.1 js file and copy the code and paste it in your local js file.**

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js